# Writing bar(variable)

Tags: r, legend

The following works as expected in R. It shows P@1, with a line over it.

```
bquote(~bar("P@"~1))
```

Instead of fixing 1, I have a variable `N`. How can I have a line over P@N, where N has a value assigned to it?

The following does not work:

```
N <- 1
bquote(~bar("P@"~N))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
bquote(~bar("P@"~.(N)))
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks!